# Why do I see differences in Tkinter between two builds?

Tags: python, tkinter

I've been using Python 2.7.2 with Tkinter.Tcl version 8.5.11, which I installed using the instructions [here](http://jholewinski.wordpress.com/2011/07/21/installing-matplotlib-on-os-x-10-7-with-homebrew/).  Recently I did another installation using the instructions [here](http://www.thisisthegreenroom.com/2011/installing-python-numpy-scipy-matplotlib-and-ipython-on-lion/#lion) in order to get SciPy to build correctly.  The newer installation also shows as Python 2.7.2 and Tkinter.Tcl 8.5.11, but the same code does not work on both installs.  I am on a Mac running OS X 10.7.2.

On the earlier install, LabelFrame() keywords "bd" and "font" are recognized, while on the second install they are not.  I can use "borderwidth" instead of "bd" on the second install.

On the earlier install, LabelFrame(text="mylabel") displays the text imbedded in the frame.  On the second install, the text is displayed outside of the frame.  From the description [here](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/onepage.html) under the heading "Label Frames", I see that is expected behavior, but it is different on the earlier install.

The biggest problem is not being able to use named fonts on the second install.

This is likely unrelated, but with the second build, importing `matplotlib.pylab as plt` and then executing `plt.plot(mydata); plt.show()` displays the plot but then frequently causes python to crash.

Any ideas how I might get this working?

Comment: are you certain you are running the exact same code? It sounds like in one you are doing `from ttk import *`. The ttk library has many of the same class names as Tkinter, but the widgets have different sets of attributes.